# How to efficiently handle huge JSON file, needs some ideas

Tags: java, json, multithreading, filesplitting

It's a questions about the train of thought, so please don't let me to use a third-party library to deal this.

Recently, I took a job interview, There's a questions like below:

**there is a huge JSON file, structure like a Database:**

```
    {
    "tableName1 ":[
       {"t1field1":"value1"},
       {"t1field2":"value2"},
          ...
       {"t1fieldN":"valueN"}
        ], 
    "tableName2 ":[
       {"t2field1":"value1"},
       {"t2field2":"value2"},
          ....
       {"t2fieldN":"valueN"}
        ],
        .......
        .......
     "tableNameN ":[
       {"tNfield1":"value1"},
       {"tNfield2":"value2"},
          ....
       {"tNfieldN":"valueN"}
    ]
   }
```

And the requirements is:

1. find some special child-node by given child-node' name and update it's field's value then save it to a new JSON file.

   2. count the number of given field's name and value.

when it's a normal size JSON file, I wrote a Utility class to load the JSON file from local and parse it to JSON Object. Then I wrote two methods to deal the two requirements:

```
void upDateAndSaveJson(JSONObject json, String nodeName,
            Map<String, Object> map, Map<String, Object> updateMap,
            String outPath) {
     //map saved target child-node's conditions
     //updateMap saved update conditions
     // first find the target child-node and update it finally save it
     // ...code ... 
}
int getCount(JSONObject json, Map<String, Object> map) {
  //map saved field target field/value 
  // ...code...
}
```

***But the interviewer let me thinking about the situation when the JSON file is very huge, then modify my code and how to make it more effective.***

My idea is write a tool to split the JSON file first. Because finally I need take the JSON Object to invoke previous two methods, so before I split the huge JSON file I know the parameters of the two methods: a Map(saved target child-node's conditions/or field target field/value), nodeName(child-node name)

so when I load the JSON file I compare the inputstream String with the taget nodeName, and then start to count the number of object the child-node, if rule is 100， then when it have 100 objects, I split the child-node to a new smaller JSON file and remove it in source JSON file.

Like below:

```
   while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){           
        for (String nodeName : nodeNames) {
            //check if its' the target node
            if (line.indexOf(nodeName) != -1) {
                //count the target child-node's object 
                //and then split to smaller JSON file
            }   
        }
    }
```

After that I can use multiple thread to load the smaller JSON file previous created and invoke the two method to process the JSON Object.

It's a questions about the train of thought, so please don't tell me you can use a third-party library to deal this problem.

So if my though feasible? or is there some other idea you guys have, please share it.

Thanks.

Comment: The problem is not related to the fact that the JSON data is huge. Rather it is the question of searching the keyword and fetch that JSON object and change/update it's values.

Comment: load it into a db and have it indexed

Comment: assuming the structure of JSON is mostly like what you have described, can you not stream and parse just one tableName1 at a time, check for the condition( fieldname, field value), dump it into the outfile (modifying field value if required), and then move on to process next (tableName) element in the stream?